# Elementwise aggregation of many vectors stored in a list

Tags: r, list, vector, aggregate, lapply

I have a list with 30 vectors of lentgh 25:

```
lst <- replicate(30, 1:25, FALSE)
```

I would like to find the median of the first elements of my 30 vectors, then the median of the second elements ... and so on, up to the 25th element.

I would like it to return a vector with the 25 values

The result for the simple example from above would read

```
#[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

I tried with `lapply` but did not succed.

Comment: `sapply(List, median)` Please give a [mcve]!

Comment: This is what happens when you don't provide a reproducible example. Everybody have their own interpretation of the question and try to answer it based on their understanding.

Comment: @nico dm is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to transpose your list first, then use `sapply`

```
lst <- list(a = 1:3,
            b = 1:3,
            c = 1:3,
            d = 1:3)

sapply(data.table::transpose(lst), median)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Same result as

```
apply(do.call(rbind, lst), 2, median)
```

---

**benchmark**

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1e5
lst <- replicate(n = n, expr = sample(100), simplify = FALSE)

library(microbenchmark)

markus1 <- function(x) sapply(data.table::transpose(x), median)
markus2 <- function(x) apply(do.call(rbind, x), 2, median)
Onyambu <- function(x) apply(t(data.frame(x)), 2, median)
PoGibas <- function(x) matrixStats::rowMedians(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = length(x)))
PoGibas2 <- function(x) matrixStats::rowMedians(unlist(x), ncol = length(x), dim. = c(length(x[[1]]), length(x)))
Maik <- function(x) sapply(lapply(1:length(x[[1]]), function(j) sapply(x, "[[", j)), median)

benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  markus1(lst),
  markus2(lst),
  Onyambu(lst), 
  PoGibas(lst),
  PoGibas2(lst),
  Maik(lst),
  times = 100
)

autoplot.microbenchmark(benchmark)
```

[image]

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  markus1(lst)   218.6485   263.9614   303.5073   302.1517   329.9800   552.4448   100
#  markus2(lst)   417.4680   509.9305   552.8606   541.3165   571.3282   823.5757   100
#  Onyambu(lst) 11038.8465 11492.1539 11972.0715 11718.6827 12193.1600 15751.3892   100
#  PoGibas(lst)   257.9104   276.8268   336.9063   344.8842   379.1340   513.6330   100
# PoGibas2(lst)   238.3503   251.9929   274.8687   257.5234   276.5978   486.7224   100
#     Maik(lst)  6423.6823  6728.7237  7044.0386  6863.9510  7222.4687  9070.8505   100
```

Comment: `apply(t(data.frame(lst)),2,median)`

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for the reply. Added a benchmark to my post.

Comment: PERFORMANCE: When using [matrixStats](https://cran.r-project.org/package=matrixStats), you can avoid the overhead that matrix creation, the `matrix()` call, introduced by specifying the matrix dimension via argument `dim.`.  Using `PoGibas2 <- function(x) matrixStats::rowMedians(unlist(x), ncol = length(x), dim. = c(length(x[[1]]), length(x)))` should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your list into a vector then to matrix and calculate row medians using `matrixStats` package:

```
foo <- list(1:25, 1:25, 1:25)
matrixStats::rowMedians(matrix(unlist(foo), ncol = length(foo)))
```

Result is vector of length 25:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I would suggest to transpose the list, so you have a list for each of the element positions in your list.

```
transpose = lapply(1:length(your_list[[1]]), function(j) sapply(your_list, "[[", j))
```

Once formatted, just call a sapply function to obtain a vector of the medians for each position in your original list:

```
result = sapply(transpose, function(x) median(x))
```

Hope it helps